# angular underscorejs _find sub objects

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I have the following data structure built by an angular factory

```
tournois {
        tournois { "tournois_id" = "1", "tournois_title"="test",etc..}
                 { "tournois_id" = "2", "tournois_title"="test",etc..}
                 {etc.}
```

With underscorejs ._find i can't manage to make it works based on tournois_id criteria, i got undefined meaning no values is found.

Any idea on the right syntax ?

```
baclyApp.factory("tournois",function($http){
//Provider qui recupère la liste des tournois
    var urlphp="http://localhost/cordova/mbacly/www/php/";
    var tournois={};   
    $http.get(urlphp+"getTournois.php").success(function(data)
     {
         tournois.tournois = data;
     })
    return {
        list: function(){
            return tournois;
        },
        find: function(cid){
                (tournois, function(tournoi){return tournois.tournois.tournois_id == cid});

        }

    }
})
```

use

```
baclyApp.controller('detailtournoisCtrl', ['$scope','$stateParams', 'tournois', function($scope, $stateParams, tournois) {
        $scope.selectedtournoi = tournois.find($stateParams.cid);
 }]);
```

Comment: I don't find a place..where you have used `_find`

Comment: Your find() function body isn't valid JavaScript. And the posted code still doesn't use _.find() anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your service function should be using `_.find`

**Factory**

```
baclyApp.factory("tournois", function($http) {
    //Provider qui recupère la liste des tournois
    var urlphp = "http://localhost/cordova/mbacly/www/php/";
    var tournois = {};
    $http.get(urlphp + "getTournois.php").success(function(data) {
        tournois.tournois = data;
    })
    return {
        list: function() {
            return tournois;
        },
        find: function(cid) {
            return _.find(tournois.tournoi,function(t) {
                return t.tournois_id == cid;
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a data structure similar to the following (based on what you described above).

```
var tournois = {
    "tournois":[
        {"tournois_id":1,"tournois_title":"test"}
        {"tournois_id":2,"tournois_title":"test"}
    ]
};
```

You would then use the _.find function from underscore.js in the following manner:

```
_.find(tournois.tournois, function(t) {return t.tournois_id === 1})
```

Of course, you'd drop this in your return statement and replace the static 1 at the end with your cid value, as in the following example:

```
return {
    find: function(cid){
        return _.find(tournois.tournois, function(t) {return t.tournois_id === cid});
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. Please mark my answer as such, if you could.

Comment: i did, but i'm too new to have it counted yet.